# How to avoid code repetition with custom color pickers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that initializes a custom color picker. however 've had to write it slightly differently for each color picker I'm initializing on-screen.

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to:
   -select all canvases in HTML and initialize them with separate Id's and draw 
   them
   - wait for a click on each individual button and thus toggle canvas, and 
   ultimately store the selected color in an input whose id will also be 
   changing.

Javascript:

```
function initColorPicker0 () {

var canvasEl0 = document.getElementById('colorCanvas0');
var canvasContext0 = canvasEl0.getContext('2d');

var image0 = new Image(250, 250);
image0.onload = () => canvasContext0.drawImage(image0, 0, 0, image0.width, image0.height); 
image0.src = "../img/color-wheel-opt.jpg";

canvasEl0.onclick = function ( mouseEvent0 ) {
    var imgData0 = canvasContext0.getImageData(mouseEvent0.offsetX, mouseEvent0.offsetY, 1, 1);
    var rgba0 = imgData0.data;

    // store
    var bannerInput = $ ( '#bannerColor' );
    bannerInput.val("rgba(" + rgba0[0] + ", " + rgba0[1] + ", " + rgba0[2] + ", " + rgba0[3] + ")" );

    // toggle visibility on color selected
    $( '#colorBox0' ).toggle();

}
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="toggleColorPicker(this);" style="display:inline-block; margin: 20px 10px;" type="button" id="0"></button>              
            <div id="colorBox0" class="brand-box color-box">
              <label for="bannerColor">Banner Background Color:
                <br>
                <input style="display:none;" class="form-control" name="bannerColor" id="bannerColor" type="text">
                <br>
                <canvas style="border-radius:50%;" id="colorCanvas0" class="color-canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
              </label>
            </div>
```

As of right now, each time I use a color picker, i re write the function accounting for the change in canvas id, as well as the ID of the input element to store the chosen color...

How can i avoid this awful code repetition?

Edit:
Attempt of what im describing:

```
    function handleColorPickers () {
    // loop through all canvas elements on page
    for ( i = 0; 1 < /* number of canvases */; i++) {

        // store each canvas in array 
        canvasArray[i] = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");

        // get context of canvas element store dynamically
        contextArray[i] = canvasArray[i].getContext("2d");

        // construct new image
        imageArray[i] = new Image(250, 250);
        imageArray[i].onLoad = () => contextArray[i].drawImage(imageArray[i], 0, 0, imageArray[i].width, imageArray[i].height);
        imageArray[i].src = "../img/color-wheel-opt.jpg";

        canvasArray[i].onclick = function ( mouseEvent /* dynamic? */) {
            // get color selection data
            dataArray[i] = contextArray[i].getImageData(mouseEvent.offsetX, mouseEvent.offsetY, 1, 1);

            rgbaArray[i] = dataArray[i].data;

            /* somehow select input dynamically, not just $('input'), & insert color value */
            dynamicInput.val("rgba(" + rgbaArray[i][0] + "," + rgbaArray[i][1] + "," + rgbaArray[i][2] + "," + rgbaArray[i][3] + ")");

            //toggle visibility 
            canvasArray[i].toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal, concrete, and verifiable example?

Comment: edited. my problem is dynamically creating variables for 1. the canvas 2. context 3. image 4. rgba data 5. selecting the container div of each canvas for toggling

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID:

```
function initColorPickers () {

    var canvasElems = document.querySelector('.colorCanvas0,.colorCanvas1,.colorCanvas2');
    var canvasContext = canvasElems.getContext('2d');

    var image0 = new Image(250, 250);
    image0.onload = () => canvasContext0.drawImage(image0, 0, 0, image0.width, 
    image0.height); 
    image0.src = "../img/color-wheel-opt.jpg";

    canvasElems.onclick = function ( mouseEvent0 ) {
         var imgData0 = canvasContext0.getImageData(mouseEvent0.offsetX, 
         mouseEvent0.offsetY, 1, 1);
         var rgba0 = imgData0.data;

         // store
         var bannerInput = $ ( '#bannerColor' );
         bannerInput.val("rgba(" + rgba0[0] + ", " + rgba0[1] + ", " + rgba0[2] + ", " + rgba0[3] + ")" );

         // toggle visibility on color selected
         $( '#colorBox0' ).toggle();

     }
}
```